# Postgresql 9.3 service unable to start

Tags: 14.04, postgresql

I have Ubuntu 14.04 machine. I'm trying to turn my server on, but there is no success. It was running months ago, but then I've disabled it on startup. Now I need to run it again. I've tried purging and installing it again and changing default port with no success.

```
$ whereis postgresql
postgresql: /etc/postgresql /usr/lib/postgresql /usr/include/postgresql /usr/share/postgresql
$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.3.5
$ sudo service postgresql start
 * Starting PostgreSQL 9.3 database server                               [ OK ] 
$ sudo service postgresql status 
9.3/main (port 5432): down
$ sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start
 * Starting PostgreSQL 9.3 database server                               [ OK ] 
$ sudo service postgresql status 
9.3/main (port 5432): down
$ sudo su - postgres
$ psql start
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Any idea why it isn't running?

Comment: Check the PostgreSQL log files.

Comment: @erik1001:  I'm experiencing the same issue. Did you found any solution?